# Указатель на ссылку?

Tags: c++, указатели, ссылки

Имеется такое определение ф-ции:

```
void uploadData(Person *& persons, int & size, std::string path)
```

Что означает `*&`? Это указатель на ссылку? Всмысле в функцию передается адрес по которому находится ссылка на объект? Если выделить память под это, то изменятся ли данные, на которые первоначально указывала ссылка? Зачем подобное вообще применяется?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это ссылка на указатель. Чтоб было понятнее, используем `typedef`:

```
typedef Person* Pperson;

Pperson p;

uploadData(p,...);
```

Т.е. при изменении `p` в функции изменения затронут и передаваемую переменную.